# Does anyone know the performance or pro/con of journey vs express?

Tags: performance, rest, node.js, express

Curious about using either framework for a REST API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well journey hasn't been updated for over 170 days. I've never heard of it before.

Where as express is being actively worked on and it has a great community.

Journey also seems to be for 0.2 so it might not work with 0.4.

I would choose express because it's properly documented and has great support.

You may also want to look at express-resources.